# Kali Linux Wireless MacBook Air (Early 2014)

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, macbook, kali-linux

I have an early 2014 13in. MacBook Air that I recently dual-booted Kali Linux onto. My problems is that the wifi will not work, and iwconfig returns only "lo". I have tried to install the broadcom drivers and firmware (into /lib/firmware), (as well as dependencies such as dkms) via usb since I do not have access to an ethernet converter at the moment, but with no luck. When I install the drivers, I notice that the console log says "could not find model by name 'wl'".

I was aware of the difficulty with wifi on the late 2013 model, but haven't read about issues with my early 2014. If I can't find a suitable way to make my on board chip work, does anyone know if a usb wifi adapter that would work? I'm new to Kali Linux and unsure of what adapters would be compatible with both my MacBook and Kali.

Thank you!

Comment: I'd use the debian HCL since Kali is based on debian.